# Find linear trend as single number google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 20 years of data. I want to find the linear trend of the %s as a single number. EG if you were to plot the linear trend, there would be a coefficient by which the line increases/ decreases over time.

Google sheets has a trend function, but it's used for creating new data based on predicting trends.

[image]

Comment: perhaps https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094249

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to answer clearly and precisely for what you want. Are you looking for the formula for the trend line? Just the correlation coefficient? Or a future value based on the info? The slope of the trend line?

What you have described is linear regression. I would suggest browsing the Insert drop down menu for formulas > statistics. There are formulas for each piece of info you want to draw (except creating the formula for you).

An easy and superficial way of obtaining the correlation coefficient and actual formula (and thus slope for linear trend lines), is to use excel. Copy your data table into excel and then create a scatterplot with the table. Go into the settings for the scatter plot and check the box for “trendline”. Then go into the trendline settings for the plot, and you can select which type of regression you want excel to use. You want linear. Towards the bottom of that menu, you want to check the boxes that say “show formula on chart” and “show R coefficient” or something along those lines. Excel will then print out your formula and coefficient in a text box on the chart. Your slope will be the coefficient of the x variable.

Hope this helps! Regression is a wormhole. I’d love to get more in depth if you’re interested!

NOTE: The outlier for year 2003 will have a significant impact on a linear regression line. Consider removing it from the data to create a line that will be more accurate for future predictions.

Comment: Consider a simple rise/run calculation from the starting point of data, to final predicted point of data.